Change of ring on the algebra of symmetric functions $\Lambda_\mathbb{Z}$
I'm reading the book "Symmetric Functions and Hall Polynomials" by MacDonald where the ring of symmetric functions $\Lambda_\mathbb{Z}$ is defined. The construction is done formally using inverse limits and then taking a direct sum (so that functions have bounded degree). A simpler, but equivalent, construction can be found in Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics (Vol. 2, Ch. 7) where $\Lambda_\mathbb{Z}$ is the subring of the formal power series ring in countably many indeterminates, $\mathbb{Z}[[x_1, x_2, \dots]]$, here each element is a sum of monomials of finite degree.
Considering power series that are homogeneous of degree $n \geq 0$ and taking only elements that are fixed by all permutations of the indeterminates, we obtain a $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\Lambda_\mathbb{Z}^n$ in a natural way. This is a graded decomposition so we define the ring of symmetric functions as
$$\Lambda_\mathbb{Z} = \bigoplus_{n \geq 0} \Lambda_\mathbb{Z}^n.$$
This construction does not necessarily need to have integer coefficients and it can be done instead over any commutative ring to yield $\Lambda_R$. MacDonald claims that this can be obtained from $\Lambda_\mathbb{Z}$ via
$$\Lambda_R = \Lambda_\mathbb{Z}\otimes_\mathbb{Z} R.$$
Since tensor product distributes over direct sum, the previous is equivalent to
$$\left(\bigoplus_{n \geq 0} \Lambda_\mathbb{Z}^n\right) \otimes_\mathbb{Z} R = \bigoplus_{n \geq 0} (\Lambda_\mathbb{Z}^n \otimes_\mathbb{Z} R).$$
This is equal to $\Lambda_R$ if $\Lambda_\mathbb{Z}^n \otimes_\mathbb{Z} R \cong \Lambda_R^n$ but I don't know how to proceed. It would be easy if $\mathbb{Z}[[x_1, x_2, \dots]] \otimes_\mathbb{Z} R \cong R[[x_1, x_2, \dots]]$, but I believe that that's false in general.

I don't know exactly what MacDonald has in mind, but when you talk about graded objects like this you don't have to specify a choice of forgetful functor to ungraded objects, and when you base change them you can base change them degree-by-degree. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1003299/is-h-mathbfc-p-infty-rx-or-rx/1003480#1003480 for a discussion.

@QiaochuYuan let me see if I understood your reference. So since I have a grading $\Lambda_\mathbb{Z}^n$ and each one of these is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, by extension of scalars, since the integers are initial in the category of commutative rings, the modules $\Lambda_\mathbb{Z}^n \otimes_\mathbb{Z} R$ are $R$-modules, so this effectively changes the base ring of the whole algebra. What is not so clear to me is why these are isomorphic to $\Lambda_R^n$.

They both have finite rank; they're just the free $\mathbb{Z}$-module resp. the free $R$-module on e.g. the symmetric functions $e_{\lambda}$ as $\lambda$ runs over all partitions of $n$, or you can choose any other standard basis of symmetric functions.

@QiaochuYuan thanks! I get it know.
